# NumberForm in logarithmic plot (with LevelScheme package)

Tags: plotting, packages, ticks

I am trying to plot some data using the `LevelScheme` package, but changing the logarithmic scale to display values in `NumberForm` instead of `ScientificForm`. I.e. I want to see the axes displaying values as `1`, `10`, `100` and `1000` instead of `10^0`, `10^1` etc. Do you have any tips on how I can achieve this?

I was trying to play with `TickLabelFunction` but I guess this is not meant to be used as I want.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
randomdata = Sort@Transpose@{
   Log[10, RandomReal[{1*^-7, 1*^-5}, 1000]],
   Log[10, RandomReal[{0.1, 1000}, 1000]]
};

ListPlot[randomdata, PlotRange -> {{-7, -5}, {-1, 3}}, Joined -> False,
 Axes -> False, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
 FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks[10, -1, 3,TickLabelFunction -> (ScientificForm[#] &)],None}, 
                {LogTicks[10, -7, -5], None}}
];
```

[image]

(Interestingly, this pseudo-data is not so randomly distributed at all ;) **edit:** nevermind, I didn't remember the data was in logspace)

Comment: Have you tried `AccountingForm` in place of `ScientificForm`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either

Comment: It is randomly distributed, just Log isn't.

Comment: When I look at the data generated for the above plot, it has points at places like {-6.96923, 2.56757}, {-6.96601, 1.27653}. How can these points be plotted in a log axis where the numbers (from 10^-7 to 10^-5) are all positive?

Comment: @bills I'm not sure I am understanding your question. Those numbers are the base 10 logarithm of the original number. I.e.   {-6.96923, 2.56757} correspond to {x,y}={10^-6.96601, 10^1.27653}. None of them are negative. What the package `LevelScheme` does is to make this correspondence

Comment: @Kuba you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a little hack to post-process the `FrameTicks` as provided by `LevelScheme`:

```
cleanTicks=Rule[FrameTicks, List[List[a_, None], List[b_, None]]] :> Rule[FrameTicks, 
   List[List[a /. DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[x_, y_]] :> 
              AccountingForm[Power[x, y]], None], List[b, None]
            ]
        ] 

ListPlot[randomdata, PlotRange -> {{-7, -5}, {-1, 3}}, 
         Joined -> False, Axes -> False, 
         Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
         FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}},
         FrameTicks -> {
         {LogTicks[10, -1, 3, TickLabelFunction -> (AccountingForm[#] &)],
          None},
         {LogTicks[10, -7, -5], None}}] /. cleanTicks /. Rational[a_, b_] :> N[a/b]
```

[image]

The `/. Rational[a_, b_] :> N[a/b]` cleans up any ratios invented by the `AccountingForm`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can get close using

```
ListLogLogPlot[10^randomdata, 
   Ticks -> {{0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001}, {1, 10, 100, 1000}}]
```

[image]

Here I"m using the built in `ListLogLogPlot` rather than the `LevelScheme` package - that's why I'm plotting `10^randomdata` so that it plots the same data.